# Having bought a return flight cheaper than a one-way, do I have to fly the second leg of the ticket?

Tags: air-travel, regulations

I purchased a ticket to fly from NYC to Santiago, Chile with a return from Bogota to NYC. Buying a round trip ticket from Santiago to Bogota is cheaper then one way so I wanted to lose the second leg of the ticket. Does anyone foresee any issues with this? It won't interfere with my Bogota to NYC flight will it?

Comment: Which airline? Is it the same for all three legs?

Comment: @neubert It's not a duplicate since this question is about not flying the *second* leg of a journey. I do recall seeing similar questions on TSE though. Wanna hunt them down?

Answer (score 1):

I don't foresee any problems as long as you put your actual departure date and flight from Bogota on your Colombian visa form (if applicable).

All a country generally wants to know about is how and when you arrived and how and when you're leaving.

As for the airline, again i don't foresee any problems (assuming that the NYC-santiago/bogota-NYC is a separate ticket to the santiago-bogota ticket and not just a multistop booking). As far as the airlines are concerned these are two independent bookings.